# How do I catch an exception for a module that I've not fully imported?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Normally, if I imported `socket`, I would be able to easily catch exceptions:

```
>>> import socket
>>> try:
...     socket.gethostbyname('hello')
... except socket.gaierror:
...     print('oops')
...
oops
```

But if I just import `socket.gethostbyname`, it won't work:

```
>>> from socket import gethostbyname
>>> try:
...     gethostbyname('hello')
... except socket.gaierror:
...     print('oops')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
```

I also get a `NameError` if I try to catch `gaierror`.

Is there any workaround for this? Is it not possible to catch an exception with a string (eg. `except 'socket.gaierror':`)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you do not want to import the full module you can simply import the exception aswell. PEP8 states that you are allowed to do.

```
from socket import gethostbyname, gaierror
```

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Answer (score 7):

In this case you should use : `from socket import gethostbyname,gaierror` and then try:

```
except gaierror:
    print('oops')
```

that's because `from socket import gethostbyname` is equivalent to:

```
import socket
gethostbyname=socket.gethostbyname
del socket
```

so `socket` is removed from from the namespace and you get that `NameError`.